# Looking for appropriate data structures

Tags: c++, c

I have data in the following form:

```
  1->  (2,3),(4,5),(6,7),(8,2)      //up to 10000 values
  9->  (4,5),(7,90),(8,1),(9,10)    //up to 1000000 values
  11-> (9,10),(11,2),(12,1)
  ...
```

I want a data structure suitable for quickly finding a value from two keys: the row and the column, so `find(9, 7)` should give `90` from the example above.

Note that the value sequences are already sorted, and that I'm more interested in lookup time than insert time.

Comment: Is this for C or C++?

Comment: Take a look at some of the other containers in the C++ STL, and actually profile your code using the best fit.

Comment: This is what, an adjacency list?

Comment: Your objection to what you have (`map<int, vector<pair<int, int> > >`) is that it does not exploit the order in the first elements, is that right?

Comment: Vector containing a pair of values is dubious. If you want a pair, you probably should use `std::pair`.

Comment: @Beta Yes you are correct :)

Comment: How about this `unordered_map<int, map<int,int> >`?

Comment: what could it _do_ with the knowledge that the elements are sorted? Save space somehow? Do _some operation_ more quickly?

Comment: @YuchenZhong Is map better than a vector..if yes can u point me to some resources...i'll be glad to exploit this more

Comment: Do you know the range of the index? If you do, you may also try some [sparse matrix representations](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mklman/GUID-9FCEB1C4-670D-4738-81D2-F378013412B0.htm).

Comment: I'm asking what you're trying to do "more efficiently". Are you trying to save space? Are you trying to save time? If so, what are you doing that you would like to be faster? You have literally given no hint of what characteristic you want to improve.

Comment: @AliceEverett, map is faster in terms of insertion speed. But yes, you need to tell us: what is more efficient?

Comment: @YuchenZhong For me efficiency means faster retrieval. I really dont care about insertion :)

Comment: And when you retrieve data, what are you doing with it? Just the hash map lookup, or do you need to find a specific item in the vector as well?

Comment: @Useless I want to find a specific item in the vector as well :)

Comment: so you have two keys, one of the row, and one of the element within the row, and you want to look up a specific element? That would have been a useful problem statement in the question. Is there anything else we should know?

Comment: @Useless No..you have summarized it pretty well :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend

```
map<int, set<pair<int, int> > >
```

`std::set` is a **sorted** container.

Note that you will have to declare the set with a comparison function (`operator<`) so that it will know to sort its pairs by their first elements.

Comment: I already have data in sorted format..would it now make a difference?

Comment: Now it would worsen the locality of each pair inside the value, but since you still haven't said what you need to do with the value, it's impossible to say if it offers some other improvement.

Comment: @AliceEverett: It will allow fast insertions and searches, because it exploits the fact that the elements are sorted.

Comment: @Beta Sorry I really did not get how does it do it. Can you please elaborate on this a bit more...sorry i am really a novice in these things

Comment: @AliceEverett: *How* does `set` do it? It performs a binary search for searching, and a merge algorithm for insertion. I'm not sure how to explain it in more detail, because I don't know how much you already know. Are you familiar with "Big O" notation? Merge sort? Binary searches?

Comment: @Beta Yes I am familiar with Big O and merge sort and binary searches. So do you mean to say that set will perform binary search by itself...whereas I will have to perform binary search when using vector myself

Comment: @AliceEverett: Don't forget fast insertion. You said you wanted speed; you can write code that will exploit the sorted state of the data, and make it as fast as mathematics allows, or you can use a container that has some of that code already built in. If that isn't what you're looking for, then I don't know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but...

```
map<int, vector<pair<int, int>>
```

is a straightforward translation of your example. Use `unordered_map` if your keys don't need to be kept in order.

This is quite efficient space-wise because the vector just packs all the pairs consecutively in memory, and each pair is just a simple struct-like object with two fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) But my question is..I have the first element of the map in sorted order and I am not exploiting this fact at all..as shown in my example .. (1,9,11,,,are all sorted). Is there a way by which the code can become more efficient by exploiting this information

Comment: You'll have to tell us what your code is doing, for us to tell you whether it can be more efficient. Are you trying to save time? space? doing _what_?

Comment: @Useless I am trying to save time. I really dont care about space

Comment: You asked about compression, which normally saves _space_ at the cost of _time_. The exception is when it helps you fit more data into each cache line or reduces the amount you have to pull over a slow bus.

Comment: This is still the best way to store the data.  When you want to retrieve an element by key, use `std::binary_search` on the vector for efficient retrieval.  You don't need a special data structure to hold the pairs.

Comment: @Useless You are very correct I would like to use compression to fit more data into each cache line or reduces the amount you have to pull over a slow bus

Comment: OK, so if you use `std::map<int, CompressedVector>`, what do you need to _do_ with the `CompressedVector` when you get it? Without knowing  this, it's impossible to suggest a good representation.

Comment: @AliceEverett: that kind of compression -- for transmission -- is unrelated to your choice of data structure for general handling of the data.

Comment: @Useless After getting the CompressedVector..i want to search within the vector

Comment: @AliceEverett: Searching compressed data is like eating a frozen turkey; you must first restore it to its original state.

Answer (score 1):

The containers you *could* use are:

- `std::map<key,value>` which gives logarithmic time lookups
- `std::unordered_map<key,value>`, which gives constant time lookups
- sorted `std::vector<pair<key,value>>`, which gives logarithmic time lookups. It takes less space than the first two, but is slower to build and the lookup code is more complicated.

The simplest thing that seems to meet your requirements is:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int,int> >
```

note that this discards some information since the value type is no longer sorted ... but the lookup behaviour should still be good.

If you want to keep the sortedness for some reason (please benchmark before claiming it's for speed), you could use

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > >
```

and use the binary search algorithms provided by the standard library (eg. `std::lower_bound`).